# Casting Any to Optional

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I am working on a set of classes that represent entities and their properties which then can create an editor table view from the entity dynamically. These properties are using generics to capture the property type. In order to use KVO and generate an automatic setter, these properties contain a key path. Here is a very simplified version of the property class:

```
class XUEntityProperty<Entity: NSManagedObject, Value> {
    let keyPath: String
    var customSetter: ((Entity, Value) -> Void)?

    func setValue(value: Value, onEntity entity: Entity) {
        /// If custom setter is set, use it.
        if let setter = self.customSetter {
            setter(entity, value)
            return
        }

        /// Otherwise set the object using the keypath.
        guard let objValue = value as? AnyObject else {
            XUThrowAbstractException() // Use custom setter
        }

        entity.setValue(objValue, forKeyPath: self.keyPath)
    }
}
```

This works very well with almost anything. The issue is when it comes to optionals. E.g.:

`let property = XUEntityProperty<MyEntity, NSDate?>(keyPath: "optionalDate")`

The issue here is that in the `setValue` method, the cast to `AnyObject` will fail since the value is `Optional<NSDate>`, which cannot be cast to `AnyObject` - `objValue as? NSDate` will return `nil` even if the `objValue` is `.Some(_)`.

And I'm looking for a solution how to solve this within the automatic setter by detecting and unwrapping the `Optional`.

Any cast I attempt leads to the compiler complaining that casting to a more optional type, or eventually enwraps the `Optional` inside another `Optional`.

Does anyone know how to **detect if a value** of `Any` **is kind of `Optional`** and if so, **extract the value** from the optional, casting it to `AnyObject`?

To give you an example to try in a playground:

```
let any: Any = Optional<String>("123")
any.dynamicType // -> Optional<String>.Type

var object: AnyObject? = nil

/// ... -> put value from `any` to `object`.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can check for optional type by adding a dummy protocol and using the `is` for type check, and there after the `Mirror(..)` for extracting the actual typed value from the optional `Any`:

```
protocol IsOptional {}
extension Optional : IsOptional {}

/* Detect if any is of type optional */
let any: Any = Optional<String>("123")
var object : AnyObject? = nil
switch any {
case is IsOptional:
    print("is an optional")
    if let (_, a) = Mirror(reflecting: any).children.first {
        object = a as? AnyObject
    }
default:
    print("is not an optional")
} /* Prints "is an optional" */

/* Detect if any2 is of type optional */
let any2: Any = String("123")
switch any2 {
case is IsOptional:
    print("is an optional")
    // ...
default:
    print("is not an optional")
} /* Prints "is not an optional" */
```

---

Charlie Monroes own final solution below is very neat (+1!). I thought I'dd add one addition to it.

Given that protocol `_XUOptional` has been defined and `Optional` type extended by it (as in Charlies answer), you can can handle events both when `any` is optional or not in one single line, using optional chaining and the nil coalescing operator:

```
let anyOpt: Any = Optional<String>("123")
let anyNotOpt: Any = String("123")
var object: AnyObject?

object = (anyOpt as? _XUOptional)?.objectValue ?? (anyOpt as? AnyObject)
/* anyOpt is Optional(..) and left clause of nil coalescing operator
   returns the unwrapped .objectValue: "123" as 'AnyObject'           */

object = (anyNotOpt as? _XUOptional)?.objectValue ?? (anyNotOpt as? AnyObject)
/* anyNotOpt is not optional and left-most optional chaining of left
   clause returns nil ('anyNotOpt as? _XUOptional' -> nil).
   In that case, right clause will successfully cast the non-optional
   'Any' type to 'AnyObject' (with value "123")                       */
```

Answer (score 3):

So, this is the solution. Needs a little workaround, but works as needed. Thanks to @dfri for the idea about the protocol!

```
private protocol _XUOptional {

    var objectValue: AnyObject? { get }

}

extension Optional: _XUOptional {

    /// This property will return nil if the value is nil,
    /// or if the value isn't castable to AnyObject. String,
    /// Int, Bool and a few others are automatically converted
    /// to their ObjC counterparts.
    var objectValue: AnyObject? {
        switch self {
        case .None:
            return nil
        case .Some(_):
            return self! as? AnyObject
        }
    }

}

let any: Any = Optional<String>("123")
let obj = (any as! _XUOptional).objectValue!
obj.dynamicType /// _NSContiguousString.Type
```

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer using `Mirror`; works neatly.

Comment: Note that you still need to assert that `any` is in fact an optional: if you test with `let any: Any = String("123")`, the above solution will yield a runtime exception due to the forced conversion (`as!`) to `_XUOptional`. I would personally prefer the `Mirror` solution as you wont need to extend the fundamental `Optional` type, but can work solely using "external" methods.

Comment: Of course, the force unwrap of the optional is for testing purposes. In real code, this looks pretty much like `if let optional = obj as? _XUOptional { return optional.objectValue }`. Or even shorter - `(obj as? _XUOptional)?.optionValue`.

Comment: Anyhow, thanks for your answers, I'm really happy to get this working! Spent almost the entire afternoon trying to fix this!

Comment: Please, do - if I've missed something. Note that the code samples I've put here are a bit simplified and taken from the Playground as oposed from the actual project, where more attention will be put to details.

Comment: Never mind, the `object = (any as? _XUOptional)?.objectValue` works really neatly, good job! :)