# Omit generic optional with `JSONSerialiser`

Tags: swift, generics, codable

When `JSONSerialiser` is used to `encode` an `Encodable` containing an `Optional` property, a `nil` value is omitted from encoding, potentially leading to an entirely empty (and nice and compact) structure. Here's an `XCTestCase` of this behaviour:

```
func test_whenNilValueIsSerialised_thenItIsOmitted() throws {

    struct Container: Codable {
        let cargo: Int?
    }

    let encoding = try XCTUnwrap(String(bytes: JSONEncoder().encode(Container(cargo: nil)), encoding: .utf8))
    XCTAssertEqual(encoding, "{}")
}
```

However, if `Container` is generic, and it is instantiated with the wrapped type as an optional, then this behaviour does not occur. The following test case fails:

```
func test_whenNilValueFromGenericIsSerialised_thenItIsOmitted() throws {

    struct Container<Cargo: Codable>: Codable {
        let cargo: Cargo
    }

    let container = Container<String?>(cargo: nil)
    let encoding = try XCTUnwrap(String(bytes: JSONEncoder().encode(container), encoding: .utf8))

    XCTAssertEqual(encoding, "{}")
}
```

The failure error is:

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("{"cargo":null}") is not equal to ("{}")

**The Question:** Is there are reasonably clean work around for this, perhaps by implementing an explicit `encode(to:)` for `Container`?

---

NB: In this case, the following solution is not appropriate:

```
struct Container<Cargo: Codable>: Codable {
    let cargo: Cargo?
}
```

… I want to be able to use a non optional as `Cargo` in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to do something like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533621/casting-any-to-optional). You will need to check if `cargo` actually is an optional type, and get the wrapped value. Then, `encodeIfPresent` that unwrapped value.

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: cargo)
    if mirror.displayStyle == .optional {
        let unwrapped = mirror.children.first?.value as? Encodable
        try container.encodeIfPresent(unwrapped.map(AnyEncodable.init), forKey: .cargo)
    } else {
        try container.encode(cargo, forKey: .cargo)
    }
}

struct AnyEncodable: Encodable {
    let wrapped: any Encodable
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try wrapped.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

Note that since the unwrapped value is of type `Any?`, you would need to cast to `Encodable`, and then wrap that in a concrete type (`AnyEncodable`).

You can write this as an extension of `KeyedEncodingContainer` too:

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encodeGenericIfPresent<T: Encodable>(_ x: T, forKey key: Key) throws {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: x)
        if mirror.displayStyle == .optional {
            let unwrapped = mirror.children.first?.value as? Encodable
            try encodeIfPresent(unwrapped.map(AnyEncodable.init), forKey: key)
        } else {
            try encode(x, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

If you encode a nested optional, where the outer optional is not nil, but the inner optional is nil,

```
JSONEncoder().encode(Container(cargo: String??.some(.none))
```

It would still produce `{"cargo": null}`. This is consistent with the synthesised `encode` implementations in non-generic cases like this:

```
struct Container: Codable {
    var cargo: String??
}
```

Comment: Cool – nice one Sweeper! I wonder what the performance hit of the `Mirror` is like? If I use this I'll measure it and see. Thanks!